# How to join two tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join

I'm trying to join two different tables to display in the foreach loop in my `index.blade` file

My Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('accounts')
            ->join('users', 'accounts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('users.accno', 'accounts.*')
            ->first();

        return view('accounts.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

My blade:

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
       <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->accno }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->balance }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->amt }}</td>
       </tr>
 @endforeach
```

My index.blade.php where I'm implementing the controller, the `{{user->accno}}` is from my user table and  the rest is from accounts table

Comment: so what seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $users = DB::table('accounts')
        ->join('users', 'accounts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('users.accno', 'accounts.*')
        ->first();
```

In your controller, you are using for `first()`. So need to use `foreach`. Just write:

```
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $user->accno }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->balance }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->amt }}</td>
   </tr>
```

Or you should use `get()` instead of `first()`. But it depends on your data if you want return only one data you should use first(). If you want to return a lot of data you should use get().
Controller:

```
$users = DB::table('accounts')
            ->join('users', 'accounts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('users.accno', 'accounts.*')
            ->get();
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
       <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->accno }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->balance }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->amt }}</td>
       </tr>
 @endforeach
```